# Wrap MediatR and infer Request/Response

Tags: c#, mediator, mediatr

We're using `MediatR` and I want to wrap `IMediator.Send` where some enrichment of the `TRequest` can happen.

```
public class RequestBase
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class RequestBaseImpl : RequestBase, IRequest<SomeResponse>
{
}

public class HandlerBase
{
    private IMediator _mediator;

    public TReturn Send<T, TReturn>(T request) where T : RequestBase, IRequest<TReturn>
    {
        request.User = new User();
        return _mediator.Send(request);
    }
}
```

The problem is that with this implementation, I have to fully type the TRequest/TResponse types when calling the Send method.

```
var response = Send(new RequestBaseImpl());
```

Gives the following compile error:

> Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'HandlerBase.Send(T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the
>   type arguments explicitly.

How can I avoid writing

```
var response = Send<RequestBaseImpl, SomeResponse>(new RequestBaseImpl());
```

Comment: This smells a bit I think - have you looked at Behaviours - https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors - this may be a cleaner way of doing what you're trying to do?

Comment: We're still using MediatR v2.1 which doesn't yet have Behaviors. And upgrading is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Have a look at pipelines in that case - https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/10/13/mediatr-pipeline-examples/ which is essentially what became Behaviours. This pattern works with v2.x